# How does Rails handle two parameters with same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, if I go to a route that is `/test?name=hi` and in the body of the request I have `{"name":"bye"}` (basically I'm trying to create a situation where params holds two keys that are equal), how does rails handle it?

I did a sample run and it seems like it takes the parameter passed in the URL over the one in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Params in rails should be scoped by the name of the model for `POST` requests.

```
def permitted_params
  params.require(:model_name).permit(:name)
end
```

so if you make a request to `POST /test?name=hi` the body should be formatted

```
{ model_name: { name: "bye" } }
```

And you'd have access to both `params[:name]` and `params[:model_name][:name]` (or `permitted_params[:name]` for the body param)

Comment: Thank you for explaining. If the linked post answer my question, should I delete this question or leave it here (since it is not entirely the same as the linked question, I believe)?

Comment: You can leave it, I agree it's not the same question exactly and it's a bit convoluted to arrive at the answer I gave after reading it.